# Make an Android device vibrate with an activity

Tags: android, vibration

I'm trying to make the Android phone vibrate with a button click within an Activity. I did a search but some said it cannot be done with Activity as it is a Context class.

Here is what I have done.

In the manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Code:

```
public class SecurityActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
{

  public Vibrator v; 
  public void vibrateStart(View view){
    v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (v != null)  v.vibrate(1000); 
  } 

  public void vibrateStop(View view){
    if (v != null)  v.cancel(); 
  }
}
```

The `onClick` in the XML will call the method defined.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it was the "Vibrate on touch" not being set in the Phone Setting.
After set it to high, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method where you want, it will help you to **vibrate the android device from our app**.

```
private void vibrate() {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds only
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {  
        v.vibrate(500); // deprecated in API 26
    }
}
```

add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```